# WMI LoadPercentage call is very slow

Tags: c#, performance, wmi

I'm trying to use WMI for checking on my CPU load (Xeon, 4 cores). I'm running XP 64 (SP2).

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> cpuInfo = new Dictionary<string, string>();


        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor");

        foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
        {
            cpuInfo.Add("LoadPercentage"+queryObj["DeviceID"].ToString(), queryObj["LoadPercentage"].ToString());
        }

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string,string> kvp in cpuInfo)
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText(String.Format("{0} {1}\n", kvp.Key, kvp.Value));
        }
    }
```

The example above runs, but is very slow, about 5 seconds. Is that a WMI problem or am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

Comment: This isn't normal.  How many lines are in the RTB?  You keep adding the same ones over and over again.

Comment: Yes. That is correct.My RTB keeps getting new lines. But I don't think that has anything to do with the slow performance, as I'm not executing this more than 2 or 3 times.                       LoadPercentageCPU0 2
LoadPercentageCPU1 0
LoadPercentageCPU2 2
LoadPercentageCPU3 0
LoadPercentageCPU0 2
LoadPercentageCPU1 0
LoadPercentageCPU2 0
LoadPercentageCPU3 0

Answer (score 0):

OK, I provide this as an answer, although it might not be - still I find it not fitting for a comment alone.

I have the same issue on Windows XP SP3 and Windows 7. As soon as I include the `LoadPercentage` property in a WMI query it runs about 1 second per physical processor (i.e. instance of `Win32_Processor`). The opposite is also true: if I include all properties in the query, but don't include the `LoadPercentage` property, it runs in a couple of milliseconds.

This behaviour can be observed with several tools, custom or OS provided (i.e. `wmic cpu`).

I can only speculate what the reason is, it might be related to the [definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394373%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of `LoadPercentage` (emphasis added):

> Load capacity of each processor, averaged to ***the last second***.
>   Processor loading refers to the total computing burden for each
>   processor at one time. This property is inherited from CIM_Processor.

The implementation of the WMI provider might actually need that 1 second to sample the load percentage "averaged to the last second" at the time you make the call. I would have guessed that the provider somehow does that in the background and only returns what it has at the time of the call. But anyhow, that is just speculation.

*UPDATE*: FWIW, the Windows 8 Developer Preview seems to show the same behavior.